# How set transparency onleft side menu in NavigationDrawerActivity

Tags: android, transparency, navigator

I am creating default Navigation Drawer Activity for my project. I would like set my left navigation bar transparent. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the the background code of NaviagtionView and him transparent

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main3"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main3_drawer" />
```